# How to have arrays in IDA's IDC

Tags: ida, idc

So to cut straight to the chase - I'm lazy, IDA is mysterious, I need to use IDA arrays in
my IDC code for convenience. Because IDC is like C(++) in its syntax I figured I could do:

```
auto lala[4] = {0,1,2,3};
```

But that doesn't work. Neither do round or square brackets.
Trying to do lala[0] produces this output:

```
Cannot use [] operator on scalars
```

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDC is closer to C than C++ but both limited in some ways and more flexible in others than C. It supports several [variable types](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/161.shtml) but arrays is not one of them:

> A variable can contain:
>
> - LONG: a 32-bit signed long integer (64-bit in 64-bit version of IDA)
> - INT64: a 64-bit signed long integer
> - STR: a character string
> - FLOAT: a floating point number (extra precision, up to 25 decimal digits)
> - OBJECT: an object with attributes and methods
>   (a concept very close to C++ class) more
> - REF: a reference to another variable
> - FUNC: a function reference

However, you can use [slice syntax](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1578.shtml) with objects to simulate arrays:

```
auto x = object();
x[0] = value1;
x[1] = "value2";
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually needed an easy way to initialise these arrays. Given a list of bytes, I wanted to be able to just put them inside braces et voila but I guess that isn't possible. I ended up using regex instead.

Comment: I looked up your profile. It's really cool you work for Hex Rays. Maybe you guys could implement arrays at some point too ;).